How do I connect socket.io to a different port while using GitHub codespaces?
I am making a program where (to make it easier for myself) I am using different ports for different pages. I already have codespaces set up and I do not want to switch to using something else, but I still want to be able to run it however I want, like if I'm programming at home when I have access to VS Code desktop. Is there a way I can have it connect to the different ports correctly using codespaces and other things?
I have tried the following code:
HTML
let socket = io(":3001");

(that file is being hosted on port 3000)
The code worked perfectly before I started using the same server to host the clients but different servers for the server-side sockets.
I have also seen documentation on namespaces and rooms. If I need to use those, how do I use them securely and which one should I use?

it sounds like you have different pages served over different ports, but the issue arises when you try to have a socket connection between the client and server on different ports (e.g., the client is served on port 3000, but the WebSocket is on port 3001).
When your HTML file (client-side code) is served from one port (3000), and your WebSocket connection is on another (3001), you are essentially dealing with cross-origin requests. Most modern browsers block this by default unless properly configured.
in your socket.io file you can ocnfigure it like this
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"]
  }
});

Adjust "http://localhost:3000" to the correct origin if needed

How do I make it work with GitHub codespaces too, where there's no localhost?
